# RuntimeError: Expected 3-dimensional input for 3-dimensional weight [128, 1024, 1], but got 2-dimensional input of size [32, 1024] instead

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, classification, pytorch-lightning

When i run the classifier with Convolutional layers, i have this error. I tried to reshape but i think that i didn't do that correctly. Its for the classification of pretrained protein embeddings. Can someone help me with this issue of shapes and dimensions i will be grateful   ?

```
import typing
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict
from typing import Optional
import numpy as np
import pytorch_lightning as pl
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F  # noqa
from deepchain import log
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_class_weight
from torch import Tensor, nn
num_layers=2
hidden_size=256
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset

def classification_dataloader_from_numpy(
    x: np.ndarray, y: np.array, batch_size: int = 32
) -> DataLoader:
    """Build a dataloader from numpy for classification problem

    This dataloader is use only for classification. It detects automatically the class of
    the problem (binary or multiclass classification)
    Args:
        x (np.ndarray): [description]
        y (np.array): [description]
        batch_size (int, optional): [description]. Defaults to None.

    Returns:
        DataLoader: [description]
    """
    n_class: int = len(np.unique(y))
    if n_class > 2:
        log.info("This is a classification problem with %s classes", n_class)
    else:
        log.info("This is a binary classification problem")

    # y is float for binary classification, int for multiclass
    y_tensor = torch.tensor(y).long() if len(np.unique(y)) > 2 else torch.tensor(y).float()
    tensor_set = TensorDataset(torch.tensor(x).float(), y_tensor)
    loader = DataLoader(tensor_set, batch_size=batch_size)
    return loader
class MLP(pl.LightningModule):
    """A `pytorch` based deep learning model"""
    def __init__(self, input_shape: int, n_class: int, n_neurons: int = 128, lr: float = 1e-3):
        """Instantiante a pytorch-lightning model
        This model is a template MLP to learn directly from embeddings.
        It's composed of 2 Dense layers with Relu activation. This template works only
        for classification model.
        The trainings logs are saved in the logs folder.
        Args:
            input_shape (int): shape input layer.
            n_class (int): number of class to predict
                           - n_class=2 for (0/1) binary classification
                           - n_class>=2 for multiclass problem
            n_neurons (int, optional): Number or neurons in each layer. Defaults to 128.
            lr (float, optional): learning rate. Defaults to 1e-3.
        """
        super().__init__()
        self.n_neurons = n_neurons
        self.lr = lr
        self.input_shape = input_shape
        self.output_shape = 1 if n_class <= 2 else n_class
        self.activation = nn.Sigmoid() if n_class <= 2 else nn.Softmax(dim=-1)
        self.model = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv1d(self.input_shape, self.n_neurons, kernel_size=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv1d(self.n_neurons, 64, kernel_size=11),
            self.activation,
        )
    def forward(self, x):
        if not isinstance(x, torch.Tensor):
            x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1)
            x = torch.tensor(x).float()
        return self.model(x), out
        

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        """training_step defined the train loop. It is independent of forward"""
        x, y = batch
        y_hat = self.model(x).squeeze()
        y = y.squeeze()
        if self.output_shape > 1:
            y_hat = torch.log(y_hat)
        loss = self.loss(y_hat, y)
        self.log("train_loss", loss, on_epoch=True, on_step=False)
        return {"loss": loss}
    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        """training_step defined the train loop. It is independent of forward"""
        x, y = batch
        y_hat = self.model(x).squeeze()
        y = y.squeeze()
        if self.output_shape > 1:
            y_hat = torch.log(y_hat)
        loss = self.loss(y_hat, y)
        self.log("val_loss", loss, on_epoch=True, on_step=False)
        return {"val_loss": loss}
    def configure_optimizers(self):
        """(Optional) Configure training optimizers."""
        return torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(),lr=self.lr)
    def compute_class_weight(self, y: np.array, n_class: int):
        """Compute class weight for binary/multiple classification
        If n_class=2, only compute weights for the positve class.
        If n>2, compute for all classes.
        Args:
            y ([np.array]):vector of int represented the class
            n_class (int) : number fo class to use
        """
        if n_class == 2:
            class_count: typing.Counter = Counter(y)
            cond_binary = (0 in class_count) and (1 in class_count)
            assert cond_binary, "Must have O and 1 class for binary classification"
            weight = class_count[0] / class_count[1]
        else:
            weight = compute_class_weight(class_weight="balanced", classes=np.unique(y), y=y)
        return torch.tensor(weight).float()
    def fit(
        self,
        x: np.ndarray,
        y: np.array,
        epochs: int = 10,
        batch_size: int = 32,
        class_weight: Optional[str] = None,
        validation_data: bool = True,
        **kwargs
    ):
       
        assert isinstance(x, np.ndarray), "X should be a numpy array"
        assert isinstance(y, np.ndarray), "y should be a numpy array"
        assert class_weight in (
            None,
            "balanced",
        ), "the only choice available for class_weight is 'balanced'"
        n_class = len(np.unique(y))
        weight = None
        self.input_shape = x.shape[1]
        self.output_shape = 1 if n_class <= 2 else n_class
        self.activation = nn.Sigmoid() if n_class <= 2 else nn.Softmax(dim=-1)
        if class_weight == "balanced":
            weight = self.compute_class_weight(y, n_class)
        self.loss = nn.NLLLoss(weight) if self.output_shape > 1 else nn.BCELoss(weight)
        if validation_data:
            x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)
            train_loader = classification_dataloader_from_numpy(
                x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size
            )
            val_loader = classification_dataloader_from_numpy(x_val, y_val, batch_size=batch_size)
        else:
            train_loader = classification_dataloader_from_numpy(x, y, batch_size=batch_size)
            val_loader = None
        self.trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=epochs, **kwargs)
        self.trainer.fit(self, train_loader, val_loader)
    def predict(self, x):
        """Run inference on data."""
        if self.output_shape is None:
            log.warning("Model is not fitted. Can't do predict")
            return
        return self.forward(x).detach().numpy()
    def save(self, path: str):
        """Save the state dict model with torch"""
        torch.save(self.model.state_dict(), path)
        log.info("Save state_dict parameters in model.pt")
    def load_state_dict(self, state_dict: "OrderedDict[str, Tensor]", strict: bool = False):
        """Load state_dict saved parameters
        Args:
            state_dict (OrderedDict[str, Tensor]): state_dict tensor
            strict (bool, optional): [description]. Defaults to False.
        """
        self.model.load_state_dict(state_dict, strict=strict)
        self.model.eval()
```

and this is the erro of dimension and shapes that i am having.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-a90a860da852> in <module>
      1 # init MLP model, train it on the data, then save model
      2 mlp = MLP(input_shape=1024,n_class=2)
----> 3 mlp.fit(embeddings_train, np.array(y_train),validation_data=(embeddings_test, np.array(y_test)), epochs=300)
      4 mlp.save("model.pt")

<ipython-input-42-a6b132d869b3> in fit(self, x, y, epochs, batch_size, class_weight, validation_data, **kwargs)
    164             val_loader = None
    165         self.trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=epochs, **kwargs)
--> 166         self.trainer.fit(self, train_loader, val_loader)
    167     def predict(self, x):
    168         """Run inference on data."""

/opt/conda/envs/bio-transformers/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in fit(self, model, train_dataloader, val_dataloaders, datamodule)
    456         )
    457 
--> 458         self._run(model)
    459 
    460         assert self.state.stopped

/opt/conda/envs/bio-transformers/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in _run(self, model)
    754 
    755         # dispatch `start_training` or `start_evaluating` or `start_predicting`
--> 756         self.dispatch()
    757 
    758         # plugin will finalized fitting (e.g. ddp_spawn will load trained model)

/opt/conda/envs/bio-transformers/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in dispatch(self)
    795             self.accelerator.start_predicting(self)
    796         else:
--> 797             self.accelerator.start_training(self)
    798 
    799     def run_stage(self):

/opt/conda/envs/bio-transformers/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/accelerators/accelerator.py in start_training(self, trainer)
     94 
     95     def start_training(self, trainer: 'pl.Trainer') -> None:
---> 96         self.training_type_plugin.start_training(trainer)
     97 
     98     def start_evaluating(self, trainer: 'pl.Trainer') -> None:

/opt/conda/envs/bio-transformers/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/plugins/training_type/training_type_plugin.py in start_training(self, trainer)
    142     def start_training(self, trainer: 'pl.Trainer') -> None:
    143         # double dispatch to initiate the training loop
--> 144         self._results = trainer.run_stage()
    145 
    146     def start_evaluating(self, trainer: 'pl.Trainer') -> None:

/opt/conda/envs/bio-transformers/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in run_stage(self)
    805         if self.predicting:
    806             return self.run_predict()
--> 807         return self.run_train()
    808 
    809     def _pre_training_routine(self):

/opt/conda/envs/bio-transformers/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in run_train(self)
    840             self.progress_bar_callback.disable()
    841 
--> 842         self.run_sanity_check(self.lightning_module)
    843 
    844         self.checkpoint_connector.has_trained = False

/opt/conda/envs/bio-transformers/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in run_sanity_check(self, ref_model)
   1105 
   1106             # run eval step
-> 1107             self.run_evaluation()
   1108 
   1109             self.on_sanity_check_end()

/opt/conda/envs/bio-transformers/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in run_evaluation(self, on_epoch)
    960                 # lightning module methods
    961                 with self.profiler.profile("evaluation_step_and_end"):
--> 962                     output = self.evaluation_loop.evaluation_step(batch, batch_idx, dataloader_idx)
    963                     output = self.evaluation_loop.evaluation_step_end(output)
    964 

/opt/conda/envs/bio-transformers/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/evaluation_loop.py in evaluation_step(self, batch, batch_idx, dataloader_idx)
    172             model_ref._current_fx_name = "validation_step"
    173             with self.trainer.profiler.profile("validation_step"):
--> 174                 output = self.trainer.accelerator.validation_step(args)
    175 
    176         # capture any logged information

/opt/conda/envs/bio-transformers/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/accelerators/accelerator.py in validation_step(self, args)
    224 
    225         with self.precision_plugin.val_step_context(), self.training_type_plugin.val_step_context():
--> 226             return self.training_type_plugin.validation_step(*args)
    227 
    228     def test_step(self, args: List[Union[Any, int]]) -> Optional[STEP_OUTPUT]:

/opt/conda/envs/bio-transformers/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/plugins/training_type/training_type_plugin.py in validation_step(self, *args, **kwargs)
    159 
    160     def validation_step(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 161         return self.lightning_module.validation_step(*args, **kwargs)
    162 
    163     def test_step(self, *args, **kwargs):

<ipython-input-42-a6b132d869b3> in validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx)
     88         """training_step defined the train loop. It is independent of forward"""
     89         x, y = batch
---> 90         y_hat = self.model(x).squeeze()
     91         y = y.squeeze()
     92         if self.output_shape > 1:

/opt/conda/envs/bio-transformers/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    887             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    888         else:
--> 889             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    890         for hook in itertools.chain(
    891                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

/opt/conda/envs/bio-transformers/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py in forward(self, input)
    117     def forward(self, input):
    118         for module in self:
--> 119             input = module(input)
    120         return input
    121 

/opt/conda/envs/bio-transformers/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    887             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    888         else:
--> 889             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    890         for hook in itertools.chain(
    891                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

/opt/conda/envs/bio-transformers/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in forward(self, input)
    261 
    262     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 263         return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
    264 
    265 

/opt/conda/envs/bio-transformers/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in _conv_forward(self, input, weight, bias)
    258                             _single(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
    259         return F.conv1d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
--> 260                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    261 
    262     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:

RuntimeError: Expected 3-dimensional input for 3-dimensional weight [128, 1024, 1], but got 2-dimensional input of size [32, 1024] instead
```

Comment: Hard to make sense of this amount of code posted, most SE users aren't going to want to dig through all this. Please be concise and only post relevant code. That being said, looks like you may need to use an `unsqueeze()` operation to add an empty third dimension to your tensor.

Comment: @DerekG I am sorry, its my first time here and sorry for this long but i wanted to post more details.
Thank you for your answer. Where should i put the unsqueeze function in this case ?

Comment: Hi, you may want to put if after `self.input_shape` in your train function.